# Is there iOS app for designing interfaces?

Tags: software-recommendation, ios, wireframing

I need an iOS app to create wireframes of iOS interface. Are there any apps similar to Balsamiq available? I don't need apps like [Marvel](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/marvel-design-apps-on-your/id765801658?mt=8) or [POP](https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/ios-productivity/id6007?mt=8). With those I can't prototype instantly in app.

Comment: Do you mean wireframe apps? Or design apps that can create mockups? See: [What is the difference between wireframes and mockups?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30860/what-is-the-difference-between-wireframes-and-mockups)

Comment: Hi user1321950 what do you mean prototype instantly? Actually creating an app with an app on your phone?

Comment: To clarify: need to wireframe app. So like balsamiq but on ios (advisible iPhone)

Comment: Wouldn't searching the App store for "wireframe" find results? There are several.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I design user interfaces for Andoid and iOS apps and use a prototyping (can do simple wireframes and full mockups) tool called [Axure](http://www.axure.com/)

I've tried quite a few tools in the past and I have found Axure to be the best so far, it's well supported with lots of tutorials and is quite versatile in what it can produce.

It allows you to design your layout/wireframe screen by screen and then 'publish' it as a mobile website optimised for iPhone screen sizes. You can open that link in your mobile browser on your device and navigate through your wireframe screen by screen. You can also save the web link to your home screen and set the app icon, so it does a very good impression of being an app.

What it doesn't do however is let you design actually on your iPhone (If that's partly what your asking?). You design on the computer and then send the designs over to your phone/tablet. I don't know of any tools to actually create mockups on the phone directly. Personally I would find it far to tricky to design anything in any detail on such a small screen, it would be very limiting. It's quick to get designs from Axure on your desktop to phone though. Once you've created a project you just hit 'publish' and then refresh the webpage on your phone.

For a better explanation of Axure's mobile capabilities than I can provide in a short post take a look at their iPhone app tutorials; http://www.axure.com/learn/iphone-app

Hope that's helpful!

Comment: Hello Annie, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!